# Scipy Sparse Eigensolver: MemoryError after multiple passes through loop without anything new being written during loop

Tags: python, memory, scipy

I'm using Python + Scipy to diagonalize sparse matrices with random entries on the diagonal; in particular, I need eigenvalues in the middle of the spectrum. The code I've written has worked fine for months, but now I'm looking at bigger matrices and am running into "MemoryError"s. What's confusing/driving me insane is that the error only shows up after a few iterations (namely 9) of constructing a random matrix and diagonalizing it, but I don't see any way in which my code stores anything extra in memory from one iteration to the next, and so can't see how my code could fail during the 9th iteration but not the 1st.

Here are the details (and I apologize in advance if I've left anything out, I'm new to posting on this site):

Each matrix I construct is 16000x16000, with 15x16000 non-zero entries. Everything ran fine when I was looking at 4000x4000-size matrices. The bulk of my code is

```
#Initialization
#...

for i in range(dim):
    for n in range(N):
        digit = (i % 2**(n+1)) / 2**n
        index = (i % 2**n) + ((digit + 1) % 2)*(2**n) + (i / 2**(n+1))*(2**(n+1))
        row[dim + N*i + n] = index
        col[dim + N*i + n] = i
        dat[dim + N*i + n] = -G

e_list = open(e_list_name + "_%03dk_%010ds" % (num_states, int(start_time)), "w")
e_log = open(e_log_name + "_%03dk_%010ds" % (num_states, int(start_time)), "w")

for t in range(num_itr): #Begin iterations
    dat[0:dim] = math.sqrt(N/2.0)*np.random.randn(dim) #Get new diagonal elements
    H = sparse.csr_matrix((dat, (row, col))) #Construct new matrix
    vals = sparse.linalg.eigsh(H, k = num_states + 2, sigma = target_energy, which = 'LM', return_eigenvectors = False) #Get new eigenvalues
    vals = np.sort(vals)

    vals.tofile(e_list)
    e_log.write("Iter %d complete\n" % (t+1))

    e_list.flush()
    e_log.flush()

e_list.close()
e_log.close()
```

I've been setting num_itr to 100. During the 9th pass through the num_itr loop (as indicated by 8 lines having been written to e_log), the program crashes with the error message

> Can't expand MemType 0: jcol 7438
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>    File "/usr/lusers/clb37/QREM_Energy_Gatherer.py", line 55, in <module>
>
>            vals = sparse.linalg.eigsh(H, k = num_states + 2, sigma = target_energy, which = 'LM', return_eigenvectors = False)
>
>    File "/usr/lusers/clb37/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.py", line 1524, in eigsh
>
>            symmetric=True, tol=tol)
>
>    File "/usr/lusers/clb37/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.py", line 1030, in get_OPinv_matvec
>
>            return SpLuInv(A.tocsc()).matvec
>
>    File "/usr/lusers/clb37/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.py", line 898, in __init__
>
>            self.M_lu = splu(M)
>
>    File "/usr/lusers/clb37/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py", line 242, in splu
>
>            ilu=False, options=_options)
> ```
>
> MemoryError

Sure enough, the program will fail during the 9th pass through that loop every time I run it on my machine, and when I try running this code on machines with more memory the program makes it through more iterations before crashing, so it looks like the computer really is running out of memory. If that's all there is to it then fine, but what I can't understand is why the program doesn't crash during the 1st iteration. I don't see any point in the 8 lines of the num_itr loop at which something gets written to memory without just being overwritten during the following iteration. I've used Heapy's heap() function to look at my memory usage, and it just prints out "Total size = 11715240 bytes" during every pass.

I feel like there's something fundamental that I just don't know about going on here, either some bug in my writing that I don't know to look for or some detail about how memory is handled. Can anyone explain to me why this code fails during the 9th pass through the num_itr loop but not the 1st?

Comment: Could you make the code complete enough to be runnable, so that people can just copypaste it and run to see the problem? Right now, it requires extra effort which raises the threshold of bothering to look at this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this seems to be reproducible on Scipy 0.14.0.

It can apparently be worked around the issue by adding

```
import gc; gc.collect()
```

inside the loop to force Pythons cyclic garbage collector to run.

The issue appears that somewhere inside `scipy.sparse.eigh` there is a cyclic reference loop, in the vein of:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass
a = Foo()
b = Foo()
a.spam = b
b.spam = a
del a, b   # <- but a, b still refer to each other and are not dead
```

This is still perfectly OK in principle: although Python's reference counting doesn't detect such cyclic garbage, a collection is run periodically to gather such objects. However, if each object is very large in memory (eg. big Numpy arrays) the periodic runs are too infrequent, and you run out of memory before the next cyclic garbage collection run is done.

So a workaround is to force the GC to run when you know there's big garbage to collect.
A better workaround would be to change scipy.sparse.eigh so that such cyclic garbage is not generated in the first place.